# php variable inside a json

Tags: php, json, paypal

I have this code for paypal single payout call, and want to add a php variable where the price is at 'value':".$planPrice." 
If instead of $planPrice I put any number for example: "1000" it works without a problem and I get the notification, but when I add the php variable it says this:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'InvalidArgumentException' with
>   message 'Invalid JSON String' in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\website\paypal_payouts\PayPal-PHP-SDK\paypal\rest-api-sdk-php\lib\PayPal\Validation\JsonValidator.php:29
>   Stack trace: #0
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\website\paypal_payouts\PayPal-PHP-SDK\paypal\rest-api-sdk-php\lib\PayPal\Common\PayPalModel.php(50):
>   PayPal\Validation\JsonValidator::validate('{\r\n ...') #1
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\website\paypal_payouts\CreateSinglePayout.php(67):
>   PayPal\Common\PayPalModel->__construct('{\r\n ...') #2
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\website\admin\reports\paynow.php(19):
>   include('C:\xampp\htdocs...') #3 {main} thrown in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\website\paypal_payouts\PayPal-PHP-SDK\paypal\rest-api-sdk-php\lib\PayPal\Validation\JsonValidator.php
>   on line 29

This is the code in php:

```
$senderItem = new \PayPal\Api\PayoutItem();
$senderItem->setRecipientType('Email')
    ->setNote('Thanks for your patronage!')
    ->setReceiver($coachUsername)
    ->setSenderItemId("2014031400023")
    ->setAmount(new \PayPal\Api\Currency("{
                        'value':".$planPrice.",
                        'currency':'USD'
                    }"));
```

Comment: Wrap $planPrice in single quotes

Comment: what's the value of `$planPrice`?

Comment: Wrapping in single quotes gives the same error

Comment: @ArensMyzyri you don't need to pass a JSON string to `Paypal\Api\Currency`, it would be simpler to use an array: `new \PayPal\Api\Currency(['value' => $planPrice, 'currency' => 'USD']);`

Comment: What is the data type of $planPrice ? Ok it holds price information but if its something 130,30 like that your json should be '130,30'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[You don't need to pass a JSON string to `Paypal\Api\Currency`](https://paypal.github.io/PayPal-PHP-SDK/docs/class-PayPal.Common.PayPalModel.html#___construct), it would be simpler to use an array:

```
$senderItem = new \PayPal\Api\PayoutItem();
$senderItem->setRecipientType('Email')
    ->setNote('Thanks for your patronage!')
    ->setReceiver($coachUsername)
    ->setSenderItemId("2014031400023")
    ->setAmount(new \PayPal\Api\Currency([
                        'value' => $planPrice,
                        'currency' => 'USD'
                    ]));
```

But if you must use JSON, it needs to be valid. JSON only allows *double* quotes for strings and key names:

```
$senderItem = new \PayPal\Api\PayoutItem();
$senderItem->setRecipientType('Email')
    ->setNote('Thanks for your patronage!')
    ->setReceiver($coachUsername)
    ->setSenderItemId("2014031400023")
    ->setAmount(new \PayPal\Api\Currency('{
                        "value":'.$planPrice.',
                        "currency":"USD"
                    }'));
```

(I'm assuming here that `"value"` should be set to a JSON number. If it's supposed to be a JSON string, replace that third-to-last line with `"value": "' . $planPrice . '",` instead.)

Comment: Great, glad I could help :)

Comment: I was doing the contrary. Put double quotes to php variable

Answer (score 2):

You should **never** generate JSON by hand.

Use the PHP function [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php). It takes care of quotes, commas, matching parentheses and everything:

```
$senderItem = new \PayPal\Api\PayoutItem();
$senderItem->setRecipientType('Email')
    ->setNote('Thanks for your patronage!')
    ->setReceiver($coachUsername)
    ->setSenderItemId("2014031400023")
    ->setAmount(
        new \PayPal\Api\Currency(
            json_encode(array(
                'value'    => $planPrice,
                'currency' => 'USD',
            ))
        )
    );
```

Even more, you don't even have to generate `JSON`. Create a new `PayPal\Api\Currency` object and use its methods [`setValue()`](http://paypal.github.io/PayPal-PHP-SDK/docs/class-PayPal.Api.Currency.html) and [`setCurrency()`](http://paypal.github.io/PayPal-PHP-SDK/docs/class-PayPal.Api.Currency.html) to set its properties.

```
$amount = new \PayPal\Api\Currency();
$amount->setValue($planPrice);
$amount->setCurrency('USD');

$senderItem = new \PayPal\Api\PayoutItem();
$senderItem->setRecipientType('Email')
    ->setNote('Thanks for your patronage!')
    ->setReceiver($coachUsername)
    ->setSenderItemId("2014031400023")
    ->setAmount($amount)
;
```

I never used PayPal API but I guess the constructor that accepts a piece of JSON is used to construct the object using the response received from the server. You should always construct empty objects and set their properties (the same way you already do for `$senderItem`) when you build a request.